# Reaching Nested State data w/ Reducer using immer

Tags: reactjs

I got data.js that contains name, listOfReview that have sub nested state(name, occupation and etc). i'm using useReducer to add another review on the listofreview. but the problem is after posting a review it will create a new object outside the listofreview. The output

```
data.js
export const data = [
    {
        id: 1607089645363,
        name: 'john',
        noOfReview: 1,
        listOfReview: [
            {
                reviewId: 1607089645361,
                name: 'john doe',
                occupation: 'hero',
                rating: 5,
                review: 'lorem ipsum',
            }
        ]
    },
];

index.js
import { data } from '../../src/data';
import { reducer } from './reducer';

const defaultState = {
    review: data
}
const ModalHandler = props => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [occupation, setOccupation] = useState('');
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState('');
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultState);

    const handelSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (name && occupation && reviews) {
            const newReview = { Reviewid: new Date().getTime().toString(), rating, name, occupation, reviews };
            dispatch({ type: 'ADD_REVIEW_ITEM', payload: newReview });
        }
    }
}

reducer.js
    export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_REVIEW_ITEM":
            return state.map((data) => {
                if (data) {
                    const newReview = [...data.listOfReview, action.payload];
                    return {
                        ...data,
                        listOfReview: newReview
                    };
                }
                return data;
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your `data` structure, you have an `array` of `listOfReview` in an `array` of `data`:-
These 2 **fixes** may help you:-

1. **FIXES 1**: You need to **pass** the **selected** `id` of `data` you want to add **new** `review` to
2. **FIXES 2**: You need to change the way you code your `reducer` so that it will **update** the `state` correctly and not `mutating` the current `state`

#### Fixes 1

- `index.js`. Adjust your `handleSubmit` to **receive** `arg` of **selected** `id` of `data` you want to add **new* `review` obj. Thus, send both 'selectedDataId' and `newReview` via `dispatch` `payload`

```js
import { data } from '../../src/data';
import { reducer } from './reducer';

const ModalHandler = props => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [occupation, setOccupation] = useState('');
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState('');
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultState);

    const handelSubmit = (e, selectedDataId) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (name && occupation && reviews) {
            const newReview = { Reviewid: new Date().getTime().toString(), rating, name, occupation, reviews };
            dispatch({ 
              type: 'ADD_REVIEW_ITEM', 
              payload: {
                selectedDataId: selectedDataId,
                newReview: newReview
              } 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

#### Fixes 2

- in `reducer`. Adjust so that it will not `mutate` your current `state`

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_REVIEW_ITEM":
      return {
        ...state,
        review: state.review.map((data) => {
          if (data.id === action.payload.selectedDataId) {
            return {
              ...data,
              listOfReview: [...data.listOfReview, action.payload.newReview]
            };
          }
          return data;
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-hill-6plv6?file=/src/App.js) of your case.

Comment: i got error of state.listOfReview is not iterable

Comment: I already updated my answer above. I didn't see your `data` is an `array` before. So above are the **fixes** to your issue

Comment: I tried to implement does fixes but still, I'm having issues on state.map is not a function - reducer.js

Comment: Done, I forgot to include that i have a defaultState value

Comment: i tried to console.log the state inside the reducer and the output is this {review: Array(1)}
review: Array(1)
0: {id: 1607089645363, name: "Andress Bonifacio", noOfReview: 1, listOfReview: Array(1)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Comment: I don't include the selectedId coz there are only one user to add a review

Comment: if there was only **one** user. Then you might ought to change the structure of your `data` to be an `object` instead of `array`. Is it intentional of you to make the `data` state to be an `array`?

Comment: can you post your `defaultState`. That would help us to counter your issue

Comment: Yap, when i created the data. js i'm planning to add user but because it's just a personal project. i just want to to have one user then i can add a multiple review on that user.

Comment: **const defaultState = {
    review: data
}**

Comment: the defaultState is equal to the data.js

Comment: Then which one should I help you with, `data` is an `array` or `object`? Btw, you can just straightaway do `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data)` instead of doing `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { review: data })` cause that's basically means, you have an `object` of `review` which contain, right now, an `array` of `data`

Comment: data is an array coz i'm planning to use this on future project. Tried to do the const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data); There's no error but i can't see what happen after the submit. But i have a separate component that will display all the value inside the listOfReview

Comment: With that being said then, let's keep your `defaultState` as `{ review: data }`. But you still need the `id` of `data` in order to **add** `newReview` in `reducer`. In future, if you have more than **one** `user`, then the code will work. I've adjusted my `reducer` code above. That will work with your current code, as long as your `defaultState` is `{ review: data }`. You may refer to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-hill-6plv6?file=/src/App.js) to see the live version.

Comment: I edited my code for reducer and also screenshot the output after submiting. The only problem is the new value of listofreview is not appearing in my current array.

Comment: Glad I can help.

Comment: Yap, the only problem i got is how to display the data on my displayReview component.

Comment: Sir lala can i ask a question abot the usereducer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225632/discussion-between-lala-and-rj30).